# Set perfect height and width for image for thumbnail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When i am uploading photos in php and I went to give preview of the image to user. I don't want to generate a separate for that. But i want to set perfect height and width of that photo to make make it look like thumbnail;

Comment: Hi :D you need to put some code...

Comment: Your question is both unclear and too broad **and contains no code** which **cannot be answered** in its present state. Can you post something that you tried where it may have failed you? That way it would have at least shown some effort on your part. **Remember,** we're always glad to help those who first help themselves. Speaking of "help"; you should go over the help area to familiarize yourself with what can and cannot be asked and what is expected of you https://stackoverflow.com/help  - By doing this, will **greatly improve** your experience on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a thumbnail class and adding any of these properties to set the 'ideal' size for the image:
max-width
min-width
max-height
min-height